# Accessibility colour contrast calculator for Linux like Colour Contrast Analyser

Tags: linux, web-development, offline, color, accessibility

On Windows I regularly used [Colour Contrast Analyser](http://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/contrastAnalyser) for determining how well websites meet visual accessibility guidelines, however I have now moved to Ubuntu, and am looking for a tool that will provide similar functionality.

Requirements:

- Offline (no web apps)
- Calculates the difference in contrast of two colours and outputs results according to [WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#visual-audio-contrast-contrast) guidelines
- Colours are entered in hexadecimal format (eg. `#FFFFFF`)

Preferred features:

- Colours are selectable from the screen (so I don't have to bother with a two-step process selecting the colours with Gpick, then copy/pasting them over)

Other:

- Native program is preferable, but a Chrome extension is acceptable if nothing else matches my criteria

Answer (score 1):

The Colour Contrast Analyzer is open source and on [github](https://github.com/ThePacielloGroup/CCA) so why not fork it and download a copy of Freepascal Lazarus and port it in your fork, (it should be reasonably trivial to do so as there are utilities for converting the DFM forms).

Comment: You know what, for all the years I have been using CCA and visiting that webpage, I had never come across the github link for the Windows source, and had thought that only the Mac port was OS. Thanks for pointing that out to me. If I get the time I will try that out, although if there are any ready-to-install Linux alternatives I would probably try them out first since spare time can be hard to come by.

Comment: I know that feeling, all to well.